# SQL - get an AVG from a COUNT

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

how you doing?

I'm trying to get the average from a count. The metric is a string, so I get an error.
I've tried some ways, but I can't. Thanks for your help

- This is the code

```
SELECT 
user_type, // works fine
newsletter, // works fine
COUNT (newsletter) as total, // Works fine 
AVG (newsletter) as percentage, // Error. No matching signature for aggregate function AVG: Supported signatures AVG(INT64), AVG(NUMERICAL), AVG (FLOAT64)
```

This is what I've unsuccessfully tried

- AVG (newsletter) as percentage
- AVG (CAST (newsletter as INT64)) as percentage
- COUNT(newsletter) / SUM(newsletter)

I would like to get a table like this

```
user_type | newsletter | total | percentage
  free.        yes.       4.       x%
  premium.     yes.       7.       x%
```

Comment: An average of what exactly? Can you share some sample data and your desired results? "Yes" as a value suggests a boolean so you could get an average (Which would be some number between 0 and 1) by doing `AVG(CASE WHEN newsletter = "Yes" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as average_newsletter_opt_in` but it's not clear if that's what you are after.

Comment: If you want to average a set of strings, you need to do something to convert those strings to numeric values first *(as per your attempt to cast it to an integer)*.  As the strings bare no resemblance to numeric values, you need to map the string values to numeric values yourself, which is why the recommendation to use something like `CASE WHEN newsletter = 'yes.' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END`, then average that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. 

I would like to get the percentage of those totals. 

For example 4 represents the 36%, and 7  represents the 64% 

Sorry...I didn't explain as supposed...It's the very first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the ratio of the current row to the whole table...

- you already have the value for each individual row
- use window functions to get the total for the whole table
- then divide the two

*(With a "window" of `()` to represent the whole table)*

```
x * 1.0 / SUM(x) OVER ()
```

In your case, `x` is `COUNT(newsletter)` which gives...

```
COUNT(newsletter) * 1.0 / SUM(COUNT(newsletter)) OVER ()
```

Comment: Hi MatBailie, 

Awesome! 

Thanks, now the table looks perfect

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the count of newsletter having value `yes` then you can use `case when` expression

```
SELECT 
user_type, -- works fine
newsletter, -- works fine
COUNT (newsletter) as total, -- Works fine 
sum (case when newsletter ='yes' then 1 else 0 end) 
from yourtable
```

Comment: Definitely. That's why I immediately changed my answer. Thanks.